# What is the definition of magnetic moment in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, definition, magnetic-moment

- The general formula for the magnetic  moment of a charge configuration is defined as $$\vec{\mu} = \frac{1}{2} \int \vec{r} \times \vec{J} \,d^3r$$
- For an electron it's said that the correct equation relating it's spin and magnetic moment is is
  $$\vec{\mu} =g\frac{q}{2m}\vec{S}$$
- It's said that the above equation cannot be justified classically and is a quantum mechanical phenomenon.

What is the definition of magnetic moment used in the quantum mechanical equation $$\vec{\mu} =g\frac{q}{2m}\vec{S}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Definition) $\vec{\mu}$ of a charge configuration is defined by
the torque $\vec{\tau}$ it feels when being in an external magnetic field $\vec{B}$
$$\vec{\tau}=\vec{\mu}\times\vec{B}$$
or equivalently by its potential energy $U$ when being in this external field $\vec{B}$
(see [Magnetic Moment - Effects of an external magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Effects_of_an_external_magnetic_field))
$$U=-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}.$$

This definition is used both for classical and for quantum-mechanical systems.

The difference begins when you want to get a relation between magnetic moment
$\vec{\mu}$ and angular momentum.
For *orbital* momentum $\vec{L}$ you have (both classically and quantum-mechanically)
$$\vec{\mu} = g\frac{q}{2m}\vec{L}\quad\text{, with } g=1$$
which can be derived theoretically and confirmed experimentally (by measuring the torque
or energy).

But for *spin* angular momentum $\vec{S}$ of the electron experiments show
$$\vec{\mu} = g\frac{q}{2m}\vec{S}\quad\text{, with } g=2.0023$$
which is roughly double the size than for orbital momentum.
This cannot be understood by classical mechanics.
But from [Pauli's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) (i.e. with non-relativistic quantum mechanics) or from [Dirac's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) (i.e. with relativistic
quantum mechanics) you can derive this formula with $g=2$.
And with the full theory of [quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics)
you can even derive it with the exact value $g=2.0023$
(see [$g$-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-factor_(physics))).

Comment: The factor $g$ is actually not exactly 2 but 2.00231930436. This value has been found both experimentally and theoretically.

Comment: @md2perpe You are right. I have improved the answer for this.

Comment: You can understand the factor of 2 using just non relativistic quantum mechanics

Comment: @Mauricio You are right. I've reread the derivation from Pauli's equation

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch,  thank you. I've seen on many places the definition of magnetic moment to be as $\vec{\mu} = \frac{1}{2} \int \vec{r} \times \vec{J} \,d^3r$  ,that's why I got confused.

Comment: According to the way you define mm say I wanted to know the mm of an electron. How would I proceed? Will I find the torque on it and the magnetic field it's in and then find a vector $x$ that satisfies $\vec{\tau}=\vec{x}\times\vec{B}$ and call that the mm?

Comment: @Kashmiri In priciple, yes. But more practical is to measure the energy difference of the electron between spin-up and spin-down with spectroscopical methods (see Zeeman effect).

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch, but how to define torque in quantum mechanics? The same as  $r$ >< $F$ ?

Comment: @Kashmiri Yes, it is $\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$.